# How to make a list perform like a queue and still return values?

Tags: java, list, sorting, queue, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to write a program using Kahn's algorithm, sort of relating to BFS. Since the Queue and the List have exact keys being put in, is there anyways to remove the queue and make the list perform just like a queue and still return values? I was told to keep the preference for the List instead of removing the keys like what a queue does. I'm not sure how to do it though. Any suggestion is appreciated. Here's one part of my program.

```
private static List<Job> topologicalSortBFS(final List<Job> jobs) //Kahn's
    {
        final List<Job> sorted = new ArrayList<>(jobs.size());
        final Map<Job, Integer> inCount = new HashMap<>(jobs.size());
        final Queue<Job> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();

        for (final Job j : jobs)
        {
            /* Associate every node with the amount of nodes it requires. */
            final int in = j.inbound.size();
            inCount.put(j, in);
            /* If the node requires nothing, then add to queue and sorted list. */
            if (in == 0)
            {
                sorted.add(j);
                queue.add(j);
            }
        }

        while (!queue.isEmpty())
        {
            final Job current = queue.poll(); // poll = pop
            for (final Job neighbor : current.outbound)
            {
                /* Remove an outgoing connection without modifying the node. */
                final int updatedIncount = inCount.get(neighbor) - 1;
                inCount.put(neighbor, updatedIncount);
                /* If node is now considered a leaf, its requirements were met. */
                if (updatedIncount == 0)
                {
                    sorted.add(neighbor);
                    queue.add(neighbor);
                }
            }
        }       
        return sorted;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) is a List : `List<Job> list = new LinkedList();` , that supports queue as well as stack functionality.

Answer (score 1):

In your given code, only the `poll( )` method is not available for the `List` object. However, `poll( )` works in `FIFO` manner, returning and removing the topmost object from the queue. Alternatively, for a `List` you can get the first element using the `get(index)` method with index value 0 and also remove it. But you should consider using a `LinkedList` as for the `remove( )` operation all the elements in `ArrayList` will be shifted for each removal, which is a costly operation. Also, `LinkedList` has the `poll( )` method as it implements the `Queue` interface.

**NOTE**: Queue fits best for the given example, my answer is just a workaround to used a List as per your question.